# is it possible to understand at Code behind whether page is being called inside iframe or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, code-behind, detect

I need to understand that whether page is being called inside iframe or not at code behind. Is this possible?

I need to determine it in master page code behind.

asp.net 4.0, C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no.

Of course you can emit client script that detects iframe and reloads the page with e.g. a querystring.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. However there's a workaround this. You can use querystring and check on page load if that querystring contains value, for example:

```
<iframe src="Default.aspx?iframe=true" />
```

In your `Default.aspx.cs` file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["iframe"]))
    {
        if(Convert.ToBoolean(Request.QueryString["iframe"])
        {
            // this page is loaded in an iframe
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this query string parameter get set?

Comment: That is an example of how to create an iframe, not how to detect one.  How would you set this value if the iframe code weren't your own, and you had to detect that your page was in that iframe?

Comment: well, it's not in the question that the iframe code is not mine. The question is whether it is possible to check that a page is loaded inside an iframe or not, no other constrains there.

Comment: I agree that the requirement is ambiguous, but I chose to read it the other way.  So your answer is fine, I just would like to see code for that piece :)  Joe seems to imply it is possible to write a client-side script for detection...

Comment: actually question is for other people not mine generated iframe :)